# Currency conversion by plugin is wrong in Cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, currency, cart

I hope someone can help me with this!
I´m using this plugin [WooCommerce Currency Switcher by PluginUs.NET.](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-currency-switcher/) everything works fine until I go to the cart page in there the price is a converter for a second time, first is converted before adding into the cart, and then inside cart page.

So I search in there support page and found this topic that suggests this [solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/currency-conversion-is-wrong-in-cart-page/) but when I add the code everything is still the same, maybe its because the code was made three years ago and now is not supported in the new Woocommerce version, this is the code that is suggested:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'fix_currency_conversion');
function fix_currency_conversion($cart_object){
            global $WOOCS;
            $cur_currency = $WOOCS->current_currency;
            $currencies = $WOOCS->get_currencies();
            $conversion_rate = $currencies[$WOOCS->current_currency]['rate'];
            if($cur_currency == 'HKD'){
                foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                    $cart_item['data']->price = $cart_item['data']->price / $conversion_rate;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: have you found any solution to this? in my case even after I tried the solution it didnt work price is still double and the subtotal is tripled, the only place it shows correctly is the total amount and the ajax cart total and the recurring total isn't changed at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is late but it will be helpful for other.

**You need to change:**

```
$cart_item['data']->price = $cart_item['data']->price / $conversion_rate;
```

**WITH**

```
$cart_item['data']->set_price($cart_item['data']->price / $conversion_rate);
```

Comment: didnt work price is still double and the subtotal is tripled, the only place it shows correctly is the total amount and the ajax cart total